# How to call factory function method inside return?

Tags: javascript

```js
function shared() {
  return {
    lot: function() {
      console.log('crawling');
    },
    pot: function() {
      lot();
      console.log("crawled");
    }
  }
}
var share = new shared();
share.pot();
```

Throwing

> error lot is not a function

how to call lot method

I have existing function structure like this, how can I call lot method without changing structure

Comment: `this.lot()` inside the `pot` method

Comment: `new` is completely useless

Comment: pot function carries an ajax request

Comment: @kunal: ajax= async -> may have a look at callbacks + promises

Answer (score 1):

```
this.lot();
```

Youre inside of an Object ( != Scope). Youre trying to get the function inside the Scope, but it isnt in the scope. Its part of the same Object so use this...

```
Scope:
window -> lot 
window -> pot //lot isnt in the scope, just window is

this:
 pot -> (this = Object ) this.lot = Object.lot
```

As Engineer pointed out, you dont need *new* as it isnt a constructor:

```
 share=shared();
 share.pot();
```